# Why is the array created by a thread return a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, variables, nullpointerexception

So here is my code

```
protected static Objects[] theObject;

private static Runnable objectDeployment = () ->    {
    MainThread.theObject = new Objects[noOfObjects];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfObjects; i++)    {
        theObject[i] = new Objects();
        theObject[i].setEnableMovement(true);
        theObject[i].start();
    }
};

private static RAMDS[] track;

private static Runnable scanner = () -> {
    int no = noOfObjects;
    track = new RAMDS[no];
    for(int i=0; i<no; i++) {
        int[] position = MainThread.theObject[i].getPosition();
        int magnitude = MainThread.theObject[i].getMagnitude();

        //check to see if there is an object within range
        if(position[0] > 0 && position[0] < Wireframe.xlimit )
            if(position[1] > 0 && position[1] < Wireframe.ylimit )
                if(magnitude > 0)   {
                    track[i] = new RAMDS(); 
                    track[i].objectId(i);   
                    track[i].start();           
                }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    noOfObjects = getNoOfObjects();
    new Thread(objectDeployment).start();
    new Thread(scanner).start();
}

}
```

So I am getting a null pointer exceprtion when thread-2 tries to access the object[i] array that should have been created by thread-1. What am I doing wrong?

And here is how I get the noOfObjects

```
private static int getNoOfObjects() {
    int deployedObjects = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many objects should be deployed?");
    deployedObjects =in.nextInt();
    return deployedObjects;
}
```

Comment: Why are you assuming thread 1 ran already?

Comment: I forgot to add this is the class Mainthread

Comment: If you need to add information, [edit] your question.

Comment: Please correct me if am wrong. Doesn't the order matter?

Comment: You mean the order in which you call `start()`? No.

Comment: And why do you assume sharing state between threads without any synchronization is a safe thing to do? It's not. Every decent tutorial about thread talks about that. Read Java Concurrency in Practice if you want to be serious about threading.

Comment: Sorry. Still new to Java and Stackoverflow

Comment: You're making it a little difficult to gain anything by threading this if the second thread must wait until the first thread creates the array and that's *all* it does.

Answer (score 1):

you need to wait for the objectDeployment thread to finish. you have a race condition. object[i] is not allocated when scanner thread is trying to use it.

edit:
split objectDeployment to init stage the is synchronized, and objectStart which start the objects. BTW, I think that the name objects is very confusing.

```
protected static Objects[] theObject;

private static Runnable objectDeployment = () ->    {
    MainThread.theObject = new Objects[noOfObjects];
    for(int i=0; i<noOfObjects; i++)    {
        theObject[i] = new Objects();
        theObject[i].setEnableMovement(true);
    }
};

private static Runnable objectStart = () ->    {

    for(int i=0; i<noOfObjects; i++)    {
        theObject[i].start();
    }
};

private static RAMDS[] track;

private static Runnable scanner = () -> {
    int no = noOfObjects;
    track = new RAMDS[no];
    for(int i=0; i<no; i++) {
        int[] position = MainThread.theObject[i].getPosition();
        int magnitude = MainThread.theObject[i].getMagnitude();

        //check to see if there is an object within range
        if(position[0] > 0 && position[0] < Wireframe.xlimit )
            if(position[1] > 0 && position[1] < Wireframe.ylimit )
                if(magnitude > 0)   {
                    track[i] = new RAMDS(); 
                    track[i].objectId(i);   
                    track[i].start();           
                }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    noOfObjects = getNoOfObjects();
    objectDeployment.run()
    new Thread(objectStart).start();
    new Thread(scanner).start();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue is the first thread creates objects and few other thread  that changes state of this objects. Now I am trying to track these changes with the scanner as they happen "its like a radar if you may". The run() method doesn't finish while the threads are still up. What do I do? Sorry it seems I don't know what am doing?

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Yeah now I look at, it is confusing. I'm to change that ASAP. That was my first code in java